# How to use global function in module exports?

Tags: node.js, node-modules

How can i use a global function inside an exported function?

Example:

**index.js**

```
const another = require('./another');
let myfunc = msg => console.log(msg);

another("Hello World!"); // This gives me myfunc is not defined
```

**another.js**

```
module.exports = msg => myfunc(msg); // myfunc is a "global" function
```

I need to do this because the code inside of another.js is recursive and i use it a lot in index.js

Comment: Why do you think `myfunc` is a global function?  Nothing you show here makes it global.  You'd have to assign it to `global.myfunc = function() {...}` to make it global.  But that's against the modularity goals of node.js.  Just put it in a module of its own and `require()` it in to any other module you need to use it from.  Then, your dependencies are all declarative and your code is completely modularity.  Global variables are generally a bad thing in node.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your another.js, you should change to

```
module.exports = (msg, callback) => callback(msg);
```

Then, in your index.js, you change to

```
const another = require('./another');
let myfunc = msg => console.log(msg);

another("Hello World!", myfunc);
```

It should work now and print on the console. This is a common pattern in nodejs